# need instance of RDD but returned class 'pyspark.rdd.PipelinedRDD'

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

Hi I have this code in Notebooks and traying to code python spark:

```
 mydataNoSQL.createOrReplaceTempView("mytable")
 spark.sql("SELECT * from mytable")
 return mydataNoSQL

def getsameData(df,spark):
result = spark.sql("select * from mytable where temeperature is not null")
return result.rdd.sample(False, 0.1).map(lambda row : (row.temperature))
```

I need an instance RDD but I am geting an class 'pyspark.rdd.PipelinedRDD'

Any help will be wellcome.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`pyspark.rdd.PipelinedRDD` is a subclass of `RDD` and it must have all the API's defined in the RDD. ie. PipelinedRDD is just a special type of `RDD` which is created when you run a map function on an `RDD`.

for example, take a look at the below snippet.

```
>>> rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(range(1,10))
>>> type(rdd)
<class 'pyspark.rdd.RDD'> ## the type is RDD here
>>> rdd = rdd.map(lambda x: x * x)
>>> type(rdd)
<class 'pyspark.rdd.PipelinedRDD'> ## after the map operation the type is changed to pyspark.rdd.PipelinedRDD
```

so you should just treat your `pyspark.rdd.PipelinedRDD` just as an `RDD` in your code.

There is no complete casting support in Python as it is a dynamically typed language. to forcefully convert your `pyspark.rdd.PipelinedRDD` to a normal RDD you can collect on rdd and parallelize it back

```
>>> rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(rdd.collect())
>>> type(rdd)
<class 'pyspark.rdd.RDD'>
```

Running `collect` on an RDD may cause `MemoryError` if the RDD's data is large.

Comment: From what I understand from your answer, it could be used as a RDD in next instruction, it will not cause any problem, it is jsut same as RDD. buy anyway, is there any way to have it back to a upper class (RDD)?

Comment: @OscarC. yes, you should treat it as an RDD. why do you want to cast it to RDD?. Since Python is a dynamically typed language you would never have to bother about casting the type of the RDD.

Comment: I need in RDD since i must to delivery an exercise in my IOT Course. The exercise is evaluated by a software, a grade, not by a person. So I have not choice to explain to this software what you and me knows, For a real case I know it is not need to cast, but this sofware does not undersand it,..

Comment: @OscarC updated the answer to convert it back to RDD.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I remember when exams and exercises were reviwed by humans...

Comment: Can you give a solution based on @OscarC. 's code ?